# How to fix a div in the middle of a three-column layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS3's multi-column layout functionality, but am having trouble finding a way to horizontally center a div such that text wraps around it. Any help would be awesome, thanks!

[Here's an idea of what I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3R34.png)

Comment: could you post some code please

Comment: How far have you got? Adding code will help see what you have tried. There is a line between "helping" and doing the whole thing for you. Cheers.

Comment: You said '..such that text wrap around it', but your sample image doesn't include any text, please update so we get a clearer idea of what you're trying to do

Answer (score 2):

Im not really sure what you want but maybe this helps you ? here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aupp7rjp/2/)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 40px;
    -webkit-column-rule-style: solid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-rule-style: solid; /* Firefox */
    column-rule-style: solid;
    -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-rule-width: 1px; /* Firefox */
    column-rule-width: 1px;
}
.yourPic{
    border:3px solid black; 
    height:60px; 
    margin-top:50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>   


 <p><b>Note:</b>Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-rule-width property.</p>
      <div class="newspaper">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
        nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi 
        enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis 
        nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        <div class="yourPic">
             picture
        </div>
        Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse 
        molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et
        accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis 
        eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer 
        possim assum.
        </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

**EDIT** Another possibility to accpomplish that is with tables. (I prefer this solution)
Here you have an example in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n29k8mhy/1/)